# Install attributes through the php installer of a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

Can anybody tell me how I can add multiple attributes in 1 install file of a custom module? In this case I also want to add them to the tab attributes but it doesn't work.

Just a beginner so I hope somebody can help me

[enter link description here](http://ideone.com/XJ5Qth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getAttributeId` accepts two parameters:

```
public function getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $id)
{
    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        $id = $this->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, 'attribute_id');
    }
    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $id;
}
```

And in your code you have three:

```
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'test1'
    'test2'
);
```

You just have to repeat `getAttributeId` and `addAttributeToSet` for each attribute.

**EDIT:**

```
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'affiliate_link2'
);

$installer->addAttributeToSet(
    'catalog_product',
    $defaultSetId,
    $groupId,
    $attributeId
);

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'affiliate_link3'
);

$installer->addAttributeToSet(
    'catalog_product',
    $defaultSetId,
    $groupId,
    $attributeId
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, I am trying it but doesn't work yet. Not sure what to do with the addAttributeToSet. In this code only the affiliate_link3 is added to the new tab Affiliate http://ideone.com/XJ5Qth

Comment: and it works thanks http://ideone.com/XJ5Qth

Comment: Hehe, you got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The actual syntax error is because you have a missing comma between your parameters. e.g:

```
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'test1'
    'test2'
)
```

should be

```
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'test1',
    'test2'
)
```

but as Reindex 'Em All has said, this function only accepts 2 paramaters so it should be

```
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'test1'
)
```

You can only get an attributeId for one product at a time.